# SSH key on dead computer

Tags: server, ssh

The machine I do all my work with (running Mint) has died. This is the machine I access my web servers (running Ubuntu) from, via SSH (using putty). I have removed the hard drive and recovered all the files in the `.ssh` folder and now wish to use another machine (running lubuntu and putty) to access my servers.
Can I use the same key and import them into putty ? If so, how would I go about this ?

My servers are public key authentication only and password access is disabled so I'm currently without SSH access to the servers and I have no physical access to them as they are somewhere in "the cloud".

Can I use the current keys? Can I create new keys?

Comment: PuTTY doesn’t use the key files in the `.ssh` directory (unless you put them there yourself). Try looking for `.ppk` files on your old computer and copy those to you new computer.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have copied the .ssh files from your old computer to your new.

To use them with `ssh` in the terminal, just place the `id_*`-files in `~/.ssh`, and do a `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/id_*`.

To use them with putty, you have to convert them to putty's format.

```
puttygen ~/.ssh/id_rsa -o ~/putty.ppk
```

This will generate `putty.ppk` in your home directory.

This can be used in putty:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Putty, on the "ssh" - "Auth" category (left menu) there is an option 
"private key file for authentication". 
Within that option you can browse your filesystem to select the private keys that you recovered from your disk.

Note that in the .ssh directory, the private key is called "id_rsa" by default.

Another way of knowing if a file is a private key is to open it and see if it contains the line

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

Comment: Note that putty does not use the same key format as openssh. You have to convert using puttygen